# Keytool: generate a secret key throws exception

Tags: keytool

I try to generate a secret key in my *.keystore, but I always get

```
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
```

The command is the following:

```
keytool -genseckey -keyalg DESede -keysize 168 -v -alias MyTestKey -keystore mykeystore.keystore
```

storetype: JCEKS

what is wrong?

UPDATE: ok, seems that `-storetype jceks` helped

is Keytool case sensitive? seems like it is not?

Comment: Is the keystore in JKS format? https://community.oracle.com/thread/1529686

Comment: thanks for the help, is keytool case sensitive? now I see my key but all with lower cases :(

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, I think they mentioned that it is case sensitive on that thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if your keystore is in JKS format. Refer to [this link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1529686) and note case sensitivity.